# Xcode: How does one fully erase the contents of an array using code only?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to empty an xcode array using code? I'm talking about a full-on clean, nothing needs to be left over.

Comment: We need to see how you defined the array and in which language you are programming (e.g. Swift or Objective-C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't say what programming language you are using in Xcode, I gonna give you solutions in both Swift & Objective-C.

Swift:

```
var array = ["a"]
// clear all elements in array
array.removeAll()
```

Objective-C:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"a", @"b"]];
[mutableArray removeAllObjects];
```

And one tip: You can refer to Apple's `Developer Documentation` from `Xcode -> Help -> Developer Documentation`. It's very useful for looking up APIs.